# access trained parameter in CNTK

Tags: cntk

With a model like this, how can one access the trained parameters like weight and bias of each layer?

```
model = Sequential ([
                Dense(xx, activation=cntk.sigmoid),
                Dense(outputs)])
z = model(features)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific mechanisms are shown in [this tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_202_Language_Understanding.ipynb). Here is the sample that shows how to access the parameters:

> model = create_model()
>
> print(len(model.layers))
>
> print(model.layers[0].E.shape)
>
> print(model.layers[2].b.value)

Comment: model.layers[0].E.shape is invalid. Is it a typo?

Comment: model.layers[0].W.shape, or model.layers[0].W.value works great. Thanks

Comment: In the context of the tutorial models.layers[0].E.shape is not defined at the point where it is created (reflected in the dim being -1. Once you hook up the model to an Input with the dimension specified, it will become a valid entity.